# Why this behavior with Nautilus Launcher in 14.04?

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher

Silly and inconsequential, but ...

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity.

When I right click on the file drawer icon for Nautilus on the launcher, I don't get a consistent response.

Sometimes, I'll see a list of all available partitions, but at other times there are only the choices: "Opens a New Window/Files/Unlock from Launcher."

Not a serious problem to be sure, but annoying nonetheless, since I haven't been able to determine any particular circumstances in what I'm doing or what apps I have open that might cause this.

Can anyone shed any light on why this occurs and/or what triggers the difference. Obviously (I think) I would like to always have it show the list of partitions, but unexplained behaviour always annoys me.

Thanks...